# OctoberCMS: How to maintain a two-way friendship relation?

Tags: mysql, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm extending the `rainlab.user` plugin to allow each user to have friends via a simple intermediate table with the following fields:

```
user_id
friend_id
status
```

I've extended the `User` model:

```
use RainLab\User\Models\User as FrontUser;

FrontUser::extend(function($model) {

    $model->belongsToMany['friends']=[
        'RainLab\User\Models\User',
        'table'    => 'meysam_social_friends',
        'pivot' => ['status'],
        'pivotModel' => 'Meysam\Social\Models\FriendsPivot',
        'timestamps' => true,
        'key'      => 'user_id',
        'otherKey' => 'friend_id'
    ];

    $model->addDynamicMethod('isFriendWith', function (FrontUser $user) use ($model) {
        $model->friends->contains($user->id);
    });

    $model->addDynamicMethod('addFriend', function (FrontUser $user) use ($model) {
        $model->friends()->attach($user->id);
    });

    $model->addDynamicMethod('removeFriend', function (FrontUser $user) use ($model) {
        $model->friends()->detach($user->id);
    });
});
```

And also extended the `Rainlab.User Controller` to have `Friends` tab where all friends of a user are listed and can be added and removed:

```
use RainLab\User\Controllers\Users as UsersController;

UsersController::extend(function($controller) {

    if(!isset($controller->implement['Backend.Behaviors.RelationController'])) {
        $controller->implement[] = 'Backend.Behaviors.RelationController';
    }
    $controller->relationConfig  =  '$/meysam/social/controllers/user/config_relations.yaml';
});

UsersController::extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context) {
    if(!$model instanceof FrontUser or $context != 'preview'){
        // friends tab should not be displayed in update and create contexts
        return;
    }

    $form->addTabFields([
        'friends' => [
            'label' => '',
            'tab' => 'Friends',
            'type' => 'partial',
            'path' => '$/meysam/social/controllers/user/_friends.htm',
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Now I need to maintain a two-way friendship relationship. i.e. whenever `user_id` and `friend_id` is added to the `friends` table, I want to automatically add `friend_id` and `user_id` to the table as well. To achieve this, I implemented `afterSave` and `beforeSave` in the `FriendsPivot` model:

```
class FriendsPivot extends Pivot
{
    /*
     * Validation
     */
    public $rules = [
        'status' => 'required'
    ];

    public $belongsTo = [
        'user' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User', 'key' => 'user_id'],
        'friend' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User', 'key' => 'friend_id']
    ];

    public function getStatusOptions()
    {
        return [
            1 => 'Pending',
            2 => 'Approved',
            3 => 'Blocked',
        ];
    }

    public function afterSave()
    {
        Log::info('Saving pivot...');

        if(!$this->friend->isFriendWith($this->user)) {
            $this->friend->addFriend($this->user);
        }
    }

    public function beforeDelete()
    {
        Log::info('Deleting pivot...');

        if($this->friend->isFriendWith($this->user)) {
            $this->friend->removeFriend($this->user);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `beforeDelete` is never called. `afterSave` gets called but `beforeDelete` never gets called and therefor the inverse of the relationship is not deleted (`user_id`-`friend_id` gets removed from database but `friend_id`-`user_id` does not get deleted). Why is `beforeDelete` not called? Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is there any better way to maintain a two-way friendship relation?

Answer (score 1):

I found this post because I'm trying to do exactly the same thing as you. If you have solved this then I wonder if you would be willing to share your solution?

Comment: I've opened an issue for this https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2747 and am trying to debug the code. I will keep you posted if anything new happens.

Comment: It's a confirmed bug now and will hopefully be fixed soon https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2747#issuecomment-297931317

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very odd at first, but maybe this is because of the special [delete behavior](https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Database/Pivot.php#L81-L103) of the Pivot model. It appears that it builds a raw query using the QueryBuilder and thus bypasses any regular Eloquent (October) events.
In my eyes, the best solution would be to trigger the delete event manually in the delete method, but I'm unsure if this has any side effects.
Maybe you could test that and prepare a PR on Github if it works.

Comment: I put a break point on this line:

https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Database/Pivot.php#L88

and realized that when I remove a friend, the `delete` method of `October\Rain\Database\Pivot` class is not called.