# Model events in pivot models

Tags: octobercms

Can [model events](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#events) be used in pivot models?
I have a many to many relation that uses a pivot model.
If I define a `beforeSave()` in the pivot model code, the function is not called. 
Should it work like this?

Comment: This is a known bug which is yet to be fixed! See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/42740344/69537 and this issue https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2747

Answer (score 0):

> pivotModel specify a custom model class to return when accessing the pivot relation. Defaults to October\Rain\Database\Pivot.

And this class doesn't contain any Events, so I think it doesn't support them.

Comment: The Pivot model extends the rainlab Model class where the events are defined. Therefore they should be fired